# Functions.php: If its single?

Tags: functions, single

i wanna put the following filter in my functions.php. But it should only be active, if its single post. In all other cases it should do nothing. Does anybody now how to do this ?

```
add_action('init', 'wpseo_set_title');

function wpseo_set_title() {
    add_filter(
        'wpseo_set_title',
        'wpseo_set_title_callback'
    );
}

function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('wpseo_set_title', 'wpseo_set_title_callback');

function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {
    if (is_single()) {
        return 'Now Single';
    }
    // return default
    return $input;
}
```

Or example from wpSEO Hilfecenter:

```
add_action('init', 'wpseo_set_title');
function wpseo_set_title() {
    add_filter(
        'wpseo_set_title',
        'wpseo_set_title_callback'
    );
}

function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {
    if (is_single()) {
        return 'Now Single';
    }
    // Else return default:
    return 'Das Buch "'. $input . '" probelesen.';
}
```

[Wordpress Conditional Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/)